# How to get last category of a self-join table

Tags: php, sql

I have a table like this (this table is my categories of products) :

```
id   title   parent_id 
 1     A         0
 2     A1        1
 3     A2        1
 4     B         0
 5     A11       2
 6     B1        4
```

now,How can I get last of sub-categories ? 
for example :

```
B1
A11
A2
```

Comment: sorry, updated my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to want the rows that are not the parent of another row:

```
select pc.*
from productcategories pc
where not exists (select 1
                  from productcategories pc2
                  where pc2.parent_id = pc.id
                 );
```

Comment: are you sure your query make this output : `B1 A11 A2`

Comment: @S.M_Emamian . . . Try running it to see.

Comment: @GordonLinoff  Suppose there is another entry with ;

id=7 title=A3 and  parent_id=1 and the above query will give wrong results.

Comment: @BuddhiMadarasinghe . . . I have no idea what your comment refers to.  With that data, ids 3, 5, 6, and 7 would be returned.  That seems to be the intent of the OP's question.

Comment: @GordonLinoff  I think OP's intent is to find the last of sub categories. In the latter case with the additional entry id=3 should be eliminated from the result set as id=7 is the last of the sub category of parent_id=1 (i.e : id 5,6,7 will be the result) . But the above answer will return all 4 of them. (ids 3,5,6,7)

Comment: @BuddhiMadarasinghe . . . I'm pretty sure you are misinterpreting the question.  I think the OP just wants the "leafs" of the hierarchy tree -- i.e., those rows that are not parents of anything else.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Then my mistake. Sorry for bothering you.

Answer (score 0):

Try below;

**My SQL version**

```
SELECT  parent_id
       ,id
       ,title
  FROM
     (
      SELECT  @row_num := IF(@prev_value=p.parent_id,@row_num+1,1) AS RowNumber
             ,p.parent_id 
             ,p.id
             ,p.title
             ,@prev_value := p.parent_id
        FROM Product p,
             (SELECT @row_num := 1) x,
             (SELECT @prev_value := 0) y
       ORDER BY  p.parent_id,p.id DESC
     ) subquery
 WHERE RowNumber = 1 AND parent_id>0 
 ORDER BY parent_id DESC
```

**MSSQL Version:**

```
 SELECT id,Title,parent_id 
 FROM ( SELECT id,Title,parent_id,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY parent_id ORDER BY id DESC) LocalId 
        FROM [dbo].[Product] ) AS P 
WHERE P.LocalId=1 
AND parent_id>0 
ORDER BY parent_id DESC
```

Comment: @S.M_Emamian: Just added the MySQL version of my suggestion. This may not be the perfect answer as I'm a newbee to mysql. Anyways give it a try.

Comment: I believe you are misinterpreting the question.  I'm pretty sure that "last of the sub-categories" is referring to the hierarchy tree that the table represents.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Yes probably I've misinterpreted the question. Sorry to bother you again.

Comment: What is ironic is that your code (at least the MS-SQL version) does produce the same results.  As for the MySQL version, you can write it with a correlated subquery.  You might try to write it that way -- it would be the same code in both databases.

Comment: @GordonLinoff  it returns only id 6,5,7.I have checked that on both versions and thank you for the suggestion. I will try it for MySQL.